# Splash screen load progress animation in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have written a windows phone application. When the application starts up it shows the splash screen which is cool and i can change the image. But is there a way to add a loading animation like those dots moving across the screen.

It would be nice if i can add one of those animation in the splash screen. Can it be done. if yes please add in your answers.

Answer (score 2):

As of right now there is no way to replace the loading image that shows up with an animation. Although there are workarounds:

1. Remove the image all together. Might want to be careful though because Microsoft requires that the application show some kind of feedback to the user within a few seconds of launching the app. Use this only if your app loads really fast.
2. Display a snap shot of the loading screen as an image so when the app does load you can show an animation with the same background image and it appears that its the same loading screen.

In your case I would recommend using a popup control with a loading animation inside (Option 2). To learn how to create a popup go [here](http://www.31a2ba2a-b718-11dc-8314-0800200c9a66.com/2011/06/how-to-create-childwindow-login-popup.html). Or if you want a well documented popup I know telerik has there [own version](http://www.telerik.com/help/windows-phone/radwindow-getting-started.html) as well.

Next place the loading message in a textblock or put your own image and animation inside of the popup. Obviously the easiest animation would be to use the Performance Progress Bar in the silverlight toolkit.

Now what you'll want to do is set the popup opened by default. Whenever your processing is done all you have to do is set the popup visibility to hidden in your C# code.

Some examples of how this is implemented can be found here:

- [Creating a Splash Screen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/priozersk/archive/2010/08/17/creating-a-splash-screen-with-a-progress-bar-for-wp7-applications.aspx)
- [Creating an Animated Splash Screen](http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/05/creating-animated-splash-screen-in.html)
- [All About Splash Screens](http://windowsphonegeek.com/articles/All-about-Splash-Screens-in-WP7-ndash-Creating-animated-Splash-Screen)

And here's an example for an XNA game:

- [Creating a Splash Screen for your XNA game](http://www.lynxinteractive.com/Blog/Creating-a-Splash-Screen-for-your-Windows-Phone-7-XNA-Game/)