# Animated dots progress bar in Windows Phone -> MS Blend 4

Tags: windows-phone-7, blend

I would like to add this simple animation to the intro screen. It shows moving dots over the screen, how to add this? Simply adding progress bar component does not do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is not possible to add simple annimations on page Starter application ("splashscreen") with file (gif) or others. However here is a very good way and example that explains how to add personal annimations "SplashScreen"

-> http://www.abhisheksur.com/2011/05/creating-animated-splash-screen-in.html

or maybe this:

-> [Splash screen load progress animation in windows phone 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7763343/splash-screen-load-progress-animation-in-windows-phone-7)